Dynamically set the root of my project in a multi-root workspace
I have the following folder structure:
.
── my_project
   ├── .vscode
   │     └── my_project.code-workspace
   └── shared_stuff
        └── .vscode
            ├── launch.json
            └── tasks.json

The shared_stuff folder includes debugger settings and it is common for  a
number of projects.
In the my_project/shared_stuff/.vscode/launch.json file I have the following settings:
"program": "/some_path/my_project/build/Debug/bin/my_project",
"cwd": "/some_path/my_project"

My problem is that I want to parametrize the root of the project and the
executable name (in the example above /some_path/my_project and
my_project), independently of the project, thus obtaining something like the following:
"program": "${my_project_path}/build/Debug/bin/${my_project_exec}",
"cwd": "${my_project_path}"

Regarding the exec I could add the following in
./my_project/.vscode/my_project.code-workspace:
 "settings": {
        "myProject.exec": "my_project"
    }

and use
"program": "${my_project_path}/build/Debug/bin/${config:myProject.exec}",

because the exec name is always the same as the project name.
However, I don't know how to resolve my_project_path. Hard-coding it is not
a good idea since different users may have my_project path in different
locations.
I noticed that the variable ${workspaceFolder} refers to
shared_stuff folder.
Nevertheless, shared_stuff is always a subfolder of a project, so in principle it would be enough to refer to the upper-folder of ${workspaceFolder}, but a more general solution would be better.

I dont know if you want to pass the values from outside to inside by parametrizing any Non-presets values in launch.json.In my opinion, I think it's not a good idea but Hard-coding for your local paths. My projects were encountered the same situation just like your this question, and finally i found the best way to execuate my different debug versions is that set these different debug configure infos in launch.json before and choose the options just like the following picture.enter image description here
